# R: How to subset multiple elements from a list

Tags: r

```
    > x
    [[1]]
    [1] "Bob"  "John" "Tom" 
    [2] "Claire" "Betsy"

    [[2]]
    [1] "Strawberry" "Banana"    
    [2] "Kiwi"

    [[3]]
    [1] "Red"
    [2] "Blue" "White"
```

Suppose I had a list `x` as shown above. I wish to subset the 2nd element of each entry in the list

```
    x[[1]][2]
    x[[2]][2]
    x[[3]][2]
```

How can I do that in one command? I tried `x[[1:3]][2]` but I got an error.

Comment: `dput(x)` would be greatly appriciated

Comment: @Adrian It is not clear how the sub elements are stored in each list element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to recreate `x`.

Comment: See my comment above?

Comment: @Adrian What is your expected result? is it `John`, `Banana`, `Blue`

Comment: list(c("Received", " from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])"), 
    c("Received", " from phobos [127.0.0.1]"), c("Received", 
    " from n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com (n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com"), c("Received", 
    " from [66.218.67.196] by n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com with NNFMP;"
    )
    )

Comment: My expected result is `"From local host (localhost [127.0.0.1])"` `"from photos [127.0.0.1]"` ... `from [66.218.67.196] by n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com with NNFMP;"`

Comment: You want your result in a list format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sapply(x2, `[`,2)
#[1] " from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])"                   
#[2] " from phobos [127.0.0.1]"                                  
#[3] " from n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com (n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com"        
#[4] " from [66.218.67.196] by n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com with NNFMP;"
```

#### data

```
x2 <- list(c("Received", " from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])"),
 c("Received", " from phobos [127.0.0.1]"), c("Received", 
 " from n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com (n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com"), 
 c("Received", " from [66.218.67.196] by n20.grp.scd.yahoo.com with NNFMP;" ) )
```