# Read multiple csv files in several directories in r

Tags: r, csv, fread

I want to read multiple .csv files from differents directories then put it in a single dataframe.

I have two kinds of directories to read:

```
E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/Ap deo/Variant/Ap_deo_1.csv

E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/Ap deo/Variant/Ap_deo_2.csv


E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/Bar soap/Variant/Bar_soap_1.csv


E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Austria/Bar soap/Variant/Bar_soap_2.csv

E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Switzerland/Ap deo/Variant/Ap_deo_1.csv

E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Switzerland/Ap deo/Variant/Ap_deo_2.csv

E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Switzerland/Bar soap/Variant/Bar_soap_1.csv


E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/Switzerland/Bar soap/Variant/Bar_soap_2.csv
```

so above directories i have so i have to read the all the files from based upon the contires which i will give in a path like as shown in path austria or switzerland...so there are many countries and like Ap deo or bar soap there are 8 categories in each countries i want to read only variants folders csv so those csv files can be 1 or 2 or 3 or sometimes more than that how can i read these files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get R to read in files from multiple subdirectories under one large directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054765/how-to-get-r-to-read-in-files-from-multiple-subdirectories-under-one-large-direc)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following.

```
base <- "E:/R_Process/R_Input_UDM/Greater Europe/CEW Hub/"
or1 <- "(Austria|Switzerland)"
or2 <- "(Ap deo|Bar soap)"

pat <- paste(or1, or2, "Variant/.*\\.csv$", sep = "/")

filenames <- list.files(path = base, pattern = pat, 
                        recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
names(df_list) <- sapply(filenames, basename)
```

Comment: that CEW HUB should be changeble like there are 4-5 more hubs and it contains different countries and those countries contains may different categories like toothpaste,mouthwash,manual TB and as there are multiple hubs so there are multiple divisions also like Greater Europe there is Latin amrica also and Asia also how can i change those?

Comment: @ShantamMalgaonkar In the answer there are two examples of the OR operator `|`. If you need to match several alternative strings just do `this|that|etc`.

Answer (score 0):

I've create this function

https://gist.github.com/Lightbridge-AI/1c5740782a63317b8516ef4fe007e256

It can read multiple CSV from a directory and put it in a list of data frame.

```
# No arg: default path = current working directory
read_dir_csv()

# Give a directory path
read_dir_csv(dir_path)

# Also, can read from every sub-directory of given directory
read_dir_csv(dir_path, recursive = T)
```

In your case with multiple directory path, you might want to loop through each path.
May be try something like this.

```
all_path <- c(path1, path2, path3 , ...)

ls <- purrr::map(all_path, read_dir_csv)
```

but, in your case `ls` is a list of list. You have to convert to list of DF first.

```
ls_of_df <- purrr::flatten(ls)
```

Then, to convert `ls_of_df` in to single DF you can use `dplyr::bind_rows()` or `dplyr::bind_cols()`