# Combining excel files from subfolders into one dataframe in R

Tags: r, excel

In a folder I have many subfolders that each contain two excel files. I'd trying to merge these files together into a dataframe in R.

```
setwd("wd")
file_list <- list.files("wd")
```

Comment: Please show some effort. This question has been asked and answered in multiple ways here on SO, whether it's a directory of excel files, CSV files, text files, tsv, tab, or various other forms, the solution is effectively the same. But the way you ask your question seems to imply that SO is a free code service. By "please show effort", I mean something like (i) *"I found these questions, but they don't work because of a, b, or c"*; (ii) *"I tried this specific code and it gives me this error"*; (iii) *"I don't understand why my code only gives me \*this\* and not \*that\* ..."*.

Comment: @r2evans I'm rather new at coding and had spent a few hours trying to solve this issue before posting anything on stackoverflow. I found no answers that would solve the specific issue I had. It is rather discouraging to new coders when one of their first experiences on stackoverflow is so negative.

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?  A)Given a folder, loop thru each sub-folder and then loop thru each excel file ?  or B)Open excel file and load into R?  It seems that the above code is the beginning solution to problem A)...  The R language requires effort to understand its many library functions.

Comment: I recognize how my comment might seem less-supportive, but this is certainly far from a *"so negative"* experience. Look, it's not about "you're horrible" or something like that, but StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. There are multiple related questions, and I will agree that SO's search does not always return perfectly-related Q/As. However, from [`[r] read multiple files`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+read+multiple+files), one of the more (though not first-listed) appropriate responses is https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050317/3358272.

Comment: Regardless, though, is that I believe you should reframe how you approach things on SO. This is not "free code service", so just stating your specifications/requirements *might* work on occasion but will more often get similar (if not more acerbic/sarcastic/caustic) responses. Much more likely to get productive responses -- and, not coincidentally, helping you learn the code platform -- please try some code, find errors, and submit that code and the errors in your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it to work with the following code.

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls", path = "wd", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, all.files = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

lst_of_frames <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel)

oneframe <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", lst_of_frames)
```

Comment: See my [other comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526213/combining-excel-files-from-subfolders-into-one-dataframe-in-r/54527408?noredirect=1#comment95890808_54527408) about the difference between `"*.xls"` and what `list.files` is expecting for a pattern. Also, your `include.dirs` looks like it would return non-files, which I would expect `readxl::read_excel` to choke on. I'm glad it works for you, though perhaps there are things in your filesystem/environment that make this work differently than "standard".

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable starting point:

```r
files <- list.files(pattern = ".*\\.xlsx$", path = "wd", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
lst_of_frames <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel)

# assuming *all* files have exactly the same structure
oneframe <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", lst_of_frames)
# if there are some *minor* differences between them, then one of the following might work better
oneframe <- dplyr::bind_rows(lst_of_frames)
oneframe <- data.table::rbindlist(lst_of_frames, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will make sure to provide more details in my future questions. The code you provided above works, but only pulls from the excel files from inside the first 10 folders, which leaves about 160 folders to go. I will work on trying to edit the code.

Comment: I'm convinced that if I can make the files variable pull all the files, rather than the first 10, then the code will work.

Comment: I added all.files = TRUE and it pulled most of the files, but not all of them.

Comment: I hear what you are saying ... and it makes absolutely no sense to me. When I do `list.files` on a large dir (with subdirs), I get no limits in the results. (I'm guessing here ...) Is it a case-thing, e.g., `*.XLSX`-vs-`*.xlsx`? Could it be that you are thinking file-globbing (as in your question) like `*.xlsx`, when it should be a *regular expression* (as in my now-correct sample code, oops, sorry) like `.*\\.xlsx$`?

Comment: If you are not familiar/comfortable with regular-expressions as opposed to file-globbing, you might like to see [`glob2rx`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/)`("*.xlsx")`, which turns your `"*.xlsx"` into the more correct (and, in this exact case, a little too-literal) `"^.*\\.xlsx$"`.