# subset a dataframe based on a matrix of row numbers and save the result in one list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame called *df* that looks like:

```
> df
   Date  A  B  C
1  2001  1 12 14
2  2002  2 13 15
3  2003  3 14 16
4  2004  4 15 17
5  2005  5 16 18
6  2006  6 17 19
7  2007  7 18 20
8  2008  8 19 21
9  2009  9 20 22
10 2010 10 21 23
```

and a matrix called *index* that looks like:

```
> index
     Resample01 Resample02 Resample03 Resample04 Resample05
[1,]          1          7          1          2          7
[2,]          3          9          2          3          8
[3,]          5          1          3          8          1
[4,]          8          3          4          9          4
[5,]         10          4          5         10          9
```

The numbers in each column stands for the row number to be selected.

> The aim is to split the dataframe into two exclusive groups of "train" and "test" according to the row numbers in each column of the matrix "index". For example for "Resample01", the result should be look like:

```
> train
   Date  A  B  C
1  2001  1 12 14
3  2003  3 14 16
5  2005  5 16 18
8  2008  8 19 21
10 2010 10 21 23
```

and

```
> test
  Date A  B  C
2 2002 2 13 15
4 2004 4 15 17
6 2006 6 17 19
7 2007 7 18 20
9 2009 9 20 22
```

and this process should be done for each colum in "index", and **the results should be saved in two lists of "train" and "test"**, in which "train" is like:

```
$train1
       Date  A  B  C
    1  2001  1 12 14
    3  2003  3 14 16
    5  2005  5 16 18
    8  2008  8 19 21
    10 2010 10 21 23

$train2
:
:
$train5
```

and "test" should be in the same format.

Only to note that my *df* accually contains 43,000 observations and the *index* matrix has 2000 columns and more than 20,000 rows. I know that subsetting for one column is easy, by doing:

```
test = df[-c(index[,1]),]
```

but for multiple columns I don't know how to do it (or loop it), and the saving form of a list seems also difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it something like this. The result should be of length `ncol(index)` and each element should hold two list elements, training and testing datasets each.

```
apply(index, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x, data) {
  # is is "demoted" from a column to a vector
  list(train = data[x, ], test = data[-x, ])
}, data = df)
```

Comment: Not clear why you are using a "data" argument. It's not a named formal in apply and you make no reference to it in your FUN argument. (I still think your code will succeed, although I would have used `sapply`.)

Comment: thank you, the code works. However the result is one list with: `sample 01 (train)(test),sample 02(train)(test),....sample2000 (train)(test)`. What I hope for are two lists: `train01 (sample01),train02(sample02),...,train2000(sample2000)`. & `test 01(sample01),test02(sample02),...,test2000(sample2000)`. Maybe I can do it by run `train = apply(train.index, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x, data) {
  list(train = sample_N_new_env[x, ])}, data = sample_N_new_env)` and `[test = apply(train.index, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x, data) {
  list(test = sample_N_new_env[-x, ])}, data = sample_N_new_env)]`

Comment: @42- it's a typo, df --> data. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698391/r-how-to-subset-multiple-elements-from-a-list) solves my problem.

by @Roman Luštrik codes:

```
listofsample = apply(index, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x, data) {
  list(train = df[x, ], test = df[-x, ])
 }, data = df)
```

following code from [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698391/r-how-to-subset-multiple-elements-from-a-list):

```
train = sapply(listofsample, `[`,1)
test = sapply(listofsample, `[`,2)
```

it produce the two lists that I wanted.